# Does declaring a reference cost any memory in C#?

Tags: c#

For example I have the following code:

```
public Class MyObject {
    string name {get; set;}
    public MyObject(){}
}
```

Would simply creating a delcaration (line 1) take any more/less space than if I declared it and assigned it a value (line 2)?

```
MyObject a;
MyObject a = new MyObject();
```

I know in the case of value types such as `int`, it would automatically allocate 4 bytes regardless of whether or not a value is assigned but in the case of a pointer-type, is is the same case?

Comment: That's a variable declaration. *It* doesn't take any space. The values/references to values stored in it do. Even with structs, it's not the *variable* that takes space, it's the struct value that does

Comment: The reason variables are declared and assigned in a single step is to make the code easier to read, reduce the scope of the variable and avoid accessing null variables by mistake. A variable declared at the top of a method remains in scope throughout that method. A variable declared outside a loop will hold the values assigned to it in the loop even after the loop terminates. *Reusing* a variable in another part of a method risks using the original values by mistake

Comment: Object references require storage as well, 4 bytes in 32-bit mode and 8 bytes in 64.  It is a pointer under the hood, the garbage collector can always find it back to know that the object is still in use.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos primitive type declarations DO take space such as in the case of an int which is why I'm wondering if the same case holds true for reference types

Comment: @HansPassant Noted! Thanks for your response. If you'd post it as an answer, I'd be happy to credit you